# ScanStreamTransformer alternative that's called once per event instead of once per listener

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I think, now I see what's going on with respect to `transform()` in `Bloc.dart` class. [ScanStreamTransformer](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/ScanStreamTransformer-class.html) inside the constructor of `BloC.dart` is called once for each listener (there are 3 listeners inside the `One.dart` class so it's called 3 times). I'd like to change this behaviour so that it's called once per event, regardless of how many listeners attached e.g. calling `_mainBloc.inValue(widget.value)` would invoke transform only once, right now it's called 3 times because there are 3 listeners (see `streamBuilder()`) inside the `One.dart` build() function.

I hope this is a little bit more clearer compared to previous post (now deleted).

```
class OneState extends State<One>{


  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _mainBloc.inValue(widget.value);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
         streamBuilder(),
         streamBuilder(),
         streamBuilder()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  streamBuilder(){
    return           StreamBuilder(
      stream: _mainBloc.values$,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<String, Future<String>>> snapshot){
        if(snapshot.connectionState  == ConnectionState.waiting) return Center(child: Container(child: new CircularProgressIndicator()));
        if(!snapshot.hasData) return Center(child: Container(child: Text("No Data"),));
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: snapshot.data[widget.value],
          builder: (contextFuture, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshotFuture){
            if(snapshotFuture.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
              return Center(child: Container(child: new CircularProgressIndicator()));

            return Center(
              child: Container(
                child: Text(snapshotFuture.data),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

}
```

BloC

```
class MainBloc{
  final ApiRequest _provider;

  MainBloc(this._provider){
    values$ = _value.stream.transform(
        ScanStreamTransformer((Map<String, Future<String>> cache, String symbol, index){
          print('transformer');
          cache[symbol] = _provider.fetchData();
          return cache;
        },
          <String, Future<String>>{},
        ));
  }

  final _value = BehaviorSubject<String>();

  Observable<Map<String, Future<String>>> values$;

  Function(String symbol) get inValue => _value.sink.add;


  dispose(){
    _value.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: whats the purpose of using that `StreamBuilder` + `FutureBuilder` combination? what do you want to achieve? maybe `ScanStreamTransformer` is not what you really need?

Comment: I have stateful widget that displays 'user' information, the class takes username as param,  inside the class data is fetched from server using username as a unique id . class has more than one streambuilder. Reason for using a map inside transformer() is to prevent screen from displaying incorrect data - when screen loads, it displays 'old' user info with 'present' user causing the screen to contain data that partially belongs to diff user objects, whereas if cache the users then I can do e.g. `snapshotFuture.data[username]`  and this seems display the entire data for specific user.

Comment: I mean you should use just `SteeamBuilder` and provide the right `Stream` that delivers your complete data (and not intermediate `Future`s)

Comment: Sometimes the stream holds the old user object and displays the old one before the new object has been fetched.

Comment: see `asyncMqp` or similar merhods

Comment: What you suggest does not work. The only method that seems prevent the data from being mixed is the above. Do you have an example?

Comment: almost every "dart stream tutorial" covers `asyncMap` as this is practically the same as `map` method - the only difference is it can be asynchronous meaning that mapper function can return `Future`

Comment: Can we just focus on the question asked without digressing? I have tried to make  the question specific as possible.

Comment: this is not digressing, this is a fundamental principle to use  `StreamBuilder` only and any data related stuff (like async stream transforming) should be done in your data model (i mean in your BLoC and not inside a nested `FutureBuilder`), a simple example: https://pastebin.com/GziDTpNC - here `switchMap` is used in `StreamBuilder` but it all depends on how you want to treat your data - check for example `asyncMap` / `flatMap` / `concatMap` as well

Comment: `"What you suggest does not work. The only method that seems prevent the data from being mixed is the above"` - does it work now? did you try to press "item #x" buttons and see the text above?

Comment: scan from the [transform_stream](https://github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform) package does what I want but needs StreamController to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.asBroadcastStream()`. Like:

```
values$ =_value.stream.transform(
        ScanStreamTransformer((Map<String, Future<String>> cache, String symbol, index){
          print('transformer');
          cache[symbol] = _provider.fetchData();
          return cache;
        },
          <String, Future<String>>{},
        )).asBroadcastStream();
```

It should stop the triple-time calling.